# Client/Server Array Issue

Tags: java, arrays, client

```
/* Now that both are arrays are sorted just combine both to the scoreboard to send to players */
    for(int k = 0; k < numCurrentPlayers; k++)
    {
        scoreBoard[k] = playerList[k] + " /" + pointTotals[k].toString();
        System.out.println(playerList[k]);
        System.out.println(pointTotals[k]);
        System.out.println(scoreBoard[k]);
    }
```

Say the contents of `playerList` is `{"Player1","Player2"}`
and the contents of `pointTotals` is `{1,3}`
and `numCurrentPlayers` is `2`.

When I run the above code the output generated is:

> Player1
>
> 1
>
> Player1
>
> Player2
>
> 3
>
> Player2

Why does it not output `Player1 /1` or `Player2 /3` on the third print statement?

Both arrays are defined as private static class variables and they are updated by other threads that are listening for the data packets coming in.  I mean that's not the problem, the contents of the arrays are correct when i receive them on the client side.  I just cannot for the life of me combine them like the code tries to do.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

```
/* The arrays to hold information for each connected user */
private static Integer[] pointTotals = new Integer[10];
private static String[] answers = new String[28];
private static BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[28];
private static String[] scoreBoard = new String[10];
private static String[] playerList = new String[10];
```

Comment: how is `scoreBoard[]` defined ? Please post that code.

Comment: just posted it, they are all class variables

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the code posted. Tried it out, and it outputs the desired result with the player1 /1 and so on - only thing i did was to put something in the arrays.

Comment: @user2328007, Looks like multithreading problem. Is your method synchronized ? If not then do that first and then execute the method.

Comment: it is synchronized, but it still doesn't work.  The arrays of players and points are being set via decoding byte[] do you think that could cause a problem?

Comment: it should not as long as final resultant array is alright. Do 1 thing, store the result into a variable and printout that variable. See what happens.

Comment: yea i have tried every possible combination of temporary store variable. Still Nothing. AHHHHHHH this is driving me crazy haha

Comment: Figured it out... TOOK ME 3 ####### HOURS. But, the issue was with when i was receiving in the data for the playersList when i created a string with a byte[] i didnt create the string with the data length so it was leaving it open ended and therefore i couldn't concat anything to it... Who woulda thought